# Tails firewall rules with static IP configuration

Tags: configuration, security, tails, firewall

Tails firewall rules with static IP configuration

Please note that this question is in relation to the connection it self. The unencrypted part of the connection not the part of the connection that goes through tor.

I am interested in knowing whether the tails firewall has two different rules sets for static IP/manual as apposed to DHCP connection?

If the Internet connection in your computer is set to static IP/manual can a server/router that has both static IP and DHCP working that is acting as the gateway server that has got hacked send packets (offer and acknowledge replay or options reply in-terms of DHCP)  to the computer that can go through the firewall that is will the firewall drop these packets since I have set my Internet connection to static IP?

Does the static IP connection (Connection between the router and device connection establishing  application only) work as a loop back only or is it unidirectional in-terms of packet used to establish a connection?

Once the connection ( static IP) is set and at a later sage if the router gets hacked can the router sends packets back (static IP connection establishing packets only)  to the device that is connected to it will these packets get dropped by the firewall?

Answer (score 1):

#### "two different rules sets for static IP/manual as apposed to DHCP?"

No, it has one config that applies to all situations.

#### "can a server/router [...] send packets [...] that can go through the firewall"

Yes, otherwise you'd never receive any replies from connection attempts.

#### "Does the static IP connection work as a loop back only or is it unidirectional?"

No, to both. How could you ever receive responses back from the internet if it was "unidirectional" or "loopback"?

#### "the router sends packets back to the device [...] will these packets get dropped by the firewall?"

No, all of the internet routed packets that you send and receive go through the device. If it dropped them you'd never connect to anything.

---

The default policy is to drop packets, unless Tails established the connection associated with them or they're on the local loopback interface. See [`ferm.conf`](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/tree/config/chroot_local-includes/etc/ferm/ferm.conf#n14).

Comment: I have made some changes to the question to make it clear. I do not thing your answer will change that much but feel free to edit your answer.

Comment: Then I think "The default policy is to drop packets, unless Tails established the connection" answers the modified question.